# Loading data in NSUserDefaults

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, nsuserdefaults

i have done the coding to save the highscore in NSuserdefaults, but i am not sure how can i load the data from the nsuserdefaults and display it in a table. PLease help.

```
NSString *name;

name = nametextbox.text;

NSDictionary *player = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name], @"name",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myScore], @"score",nil];
[highScore addObject:player];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"score" ascending:NO];
[highScore sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
[sort release];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:highScore forKey:@"highScore"];
```

Comment: @Jonathan Sterling reviewing some of your most recent comments on SO, you might want to turn it down a notch or two.

Comment: Disagree. (Also, whoever fixed this, thank you!). There are a lot of questions which have valid content, but are marred by impossibly terrible spelling and poor statement. I think it's the least we can expect from new users, to at least ask questions coherently and use something resembling the proper terms.

Comment: Moreover, by linking to the Markdown syntax guide, I'm being constructive. That's the difference between a bitchy troll and a frustrated person trying to help.

Comment: @Jonathan Sterling Bitchy is the correct adjective. You can be helpful without the snark.

Comment: Cool story, bro. You're entitled to your opinion.

Comment: @Jonathan Sterling Your age is showing now. Be mindful that your tone towards new users, especially, is counterproductive towards the growth of the site.

Comment: Commenting on my age is a nice example of DH1 (http://www.paulgraham.com/disagree.html). As to your second comment, you're welcome to think that. Personally, I don't think that the sort of growth on SO that increases the noise-to-signal ratio is helpful; I'd prefer the site to grow slowly, but be filled with interesting discussion, than to be filled with hopeless "plz teh coedz" users/questions. I often browse SO to learn from awesome masters (like @bbum, etc.), but frequently am drowned in all of the noise. SO is becoming less of a learning experience, and more of a frustration.

Comment: I'm not interested in cluttering the comments section any more on this question by arguing with you. If you have a problem with me, email me (jonsterling@me.com), and I'll try to iron this out with you. Otherwise, stop insulting and complaining: we'll just have to disagree.

Comment: @Jonathan Sterling This is what I meant about age; I was talking about a lack of maturity in some of your responses. I think you got the point, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to load it just the way you'd expect (like accessing a value in an `NSDictionary`):

```
NSArray *highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"highScore"];
```

**Update**

To display the data from this array in a table view, you'll need to create a view controller and use the array as your data source. The easiest way to do this is by subclassing `UITableViewController`. This should get you started on the implementation of that controller:

```
// HighScoreViewController.h

@interface HighScoreViewController : UITableViewController {
  NSArray *highScores;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *highScores;
@end
```

.

```
// HighScoreViewController.m

#import HighScoreViewController.h

static const NSInteger kNameLabelTag = 1337;
static const NSInteger kScoreLabelTag = 5555;

@implementation HighScoreViewController
@synthesize highScores;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [self setHighScores:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                       objectForKey:@"highScore"]];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [self.highScores count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"PlayerCell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if (cel == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
             reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

    // Create UILabels for name and score and add them to your cell
    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel new] autorelease];
    [nameLabel setTag:kNameLabelTag];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];

    UILabel *scoreLabel = [[UILabel new] autorelease];
    [scoreLabel setTag:kScoreLabelTag];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:scoreLabel];

    // Set other attributes common to all of your cells here
    // You will also need to set the frames of these labels (nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(...))
  }

  NSDictionary *player = [self.highScores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSString *name = [player objectForKey:@"name"];
  NSString *score = [player objectForKey:@"score"];

  [(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kNameLabelTag] setText:name];
  [(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kScoreLabelTag] setText:score];

  return cell;
}

@end
```

A key thing to remember with `UITableView` is that cells get reused, so you need to be careful about where you initialize/configure your cell's subviews.

Comment: I have the line of coding. But i am not sure how to display it into the table view with name on one side and the score on the other. Sorry, i am new to this programming.

Comment: thanks for the coding. but how do i set the frames so that it will be constant for all the array

Comment: Replace the comments at the end of that `if` block with `nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(...);` (replacing ... with the right arguments). Do the same for `scoreLabel`.