# UITableView - Loading Data from NSUserDefaults

Tags: xcode, nsuserdefaults, tableview

I'm fairly new to programming with xCode. I try to understand the basics by reading books/tutorials and so on. But sometimes even those can't help. And even thought I always see a challenge in finding out where the error is or what to do, I'm baffled about this one.

I created a normal UITableView. I want the User to enter information in three different UITextFields which are all saved to NSUserDefaults. When doing so, it saves them correctly and I can load them in a normal label.

But I want it to get displayed in one Cell (along with the User's Name that should be saved permanently, so he/she doesnt have to type it over and over again). So when the user enters the data, it will get saved in NSUserDefaults and whenever he switches to the TableView it will get displayed in the first row altogether.

(For example) I tried Cameron Spickerts answer [Loading data in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332565/loading-data-in-nsuserdefaults) (changed it to my needs ofc). But I can't seem to get it to work. Maybe because he uses an much older version of xCode? I would be really grateful, if someone could help me with this problem.

Code from .m file:

```
 @synthesize tableViewArray;



 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[self.UserData arrayWithObjects:[prefs objectForKey:@"hello"], [prefs objectForKey:@"ha
ello2"], [prefs objectForKey:@"hello3"] nil];


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return [tableViewArray count];
   }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", [self.UserData objectAtIndex:0], [self.UserData objectAtIndex:1], [self.UserData objectAtIndex:2] ];

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You selected %@",[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" 
                                                    message: message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
```

}

Comment: You'll need to post the actual code that isn't working so we can see what's happening.

Comment: `... [prefs objectForKey:@"hello3"], nil]; ...` comma before `nil`

Comment: because you haven't made a property userData?.. You need to create it in the interface and synthesize in the implementation parts.

Comment: Well I tried, but he won't let me, because of unknown type name.

Comment: add this in interface: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *userData;`, this in the implementation `@synthesize userData;` and it'll be fine (if you are not using auto reference count, otherwise type `strong` instead of `retain`)

Comment: Thanks again, now it works, I also found my mistake (Just a typo -.-). Well, now it says at code [self.userData(..)] Receiver type NSArray for instace message does not declare a method with selector arrayWithObjects - Like I said, I'm fairly new to said, and just started up on reading about TableViews, so sorry if I dont see my mistakes right away.

Comment: `arrayWithObjects` is not an instance method, it's a class method, my mistake. Try `self.userData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Found out what the problem is, thanky everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement several `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods. For that, make sure you use a subclass of `UITableViewController` or your ViewController conforms to these protocols. Like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

For example, you store your data from `NSUserDefaults` in `self.userData` property, which is a array. You should fill this `NSArray` for example in your `-viewDidLoad` method.

Then, make sure you have these methods implemented:

```
// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

// Set up the number of rows
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.userData count];
}
```

Implementation of the next method depends on your iOS version, in iOS5 you will write this:

```
// Then fill the cells with data
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.userData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Then follows non-essentional in your case methods of `UITableViewDelegate`, you can define them later.

Make sure you have proper bindings in your interface builder or storyboards. Your tableViews's `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets have to be bound to your ViewController.

Hope it helps. It'll help me to answer exactly to the point, if you show me your code.

Comment: I cant post my code just yet, have to wait a few hours until I can reply to my own question, but Ill try your solution and get back to you, thanks :) BUT I have a question: How can I sstore data in self.UserData?

Comment: I tried to add you some points, maybe they allow you to answer. Up my answer to, if you may )

Comment: I've made a new answer, try it. And feel free to up and mark as a suitable answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, answer to

> How can I store data in `self.UserData?`

It' really easy. Like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:_value forKey:@"yourUserDefaultsEntryName"];
```

You can read it then

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[self.UserData arrayWithObjects:[prefs objectForKey:@"yourUserDefaultsEntryName"], [prefs objectForKey:@"yourAnotherUserDefaultsEntryName"], nil];
```

Hope that'll help.

Comment: Thanks, but I think we mean two different things. The user can save what he enters in the three textfields. But I want them to get displayed in the tableview in one cell. I thought you meant I could save all three inputs with the above code. But either I was mistaken or it doesnt work. I get an error for UserData

Comment: I gave you a sample. You can save as many UserDefaults as you wish.

Comment: To show all three preferences in one cell just write something like this in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method: `cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", [self.UserData objectAtIndex:0], [self.UserData objectAtIndex:1], [self.UserData objectAtIndex:2] ];`

Comment: I know, I know :) Like I said, I already did that, (english is not my native language, so maybe I said something wrong). I put the read-part in my view didload but it gives me an error for UserData and says "expected ; after expression" at [prefs objectForKey:@"yourUserDefaultsEntryName"] - And dont worry, I will mark it as usable answer, but cant atm because of too few prestige.

Comment: Do you have a plattform I can contact you on? Or I give you one of mine, so I can send you the code, maybe its better to understand then?

Comment: If it's telling you about ` ; ` that means that you've forgot either `;` or some other character like `[ ]` or haven't made a parameter for a method (i.e. `[self.userData arrayWithObjects:]`) in general case...

Comment: Check my user info — feel free to use email

Comment: Thanks, but it finally let met add my code, you can see it in first post :)